# How does the functional differentiation of the partition function produce the disconnected graphs?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

Quoting from *A Modern Introduction to Quantum Field Theory* by Maggiore (chapter 9):
$$W[0]=\int {\cal D}\phi\, e^{iS}\tag{9.41}$$
$$W[J]=W[0]\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2} \int d^{4}x\int d^{4}y\, J(x) D(x-y)J(y)\right\}.\tag{9.43}$$
Then
$$Z[J]=\log W[J]\tag{9.47}$$
is the generating functional of the connected Green's functions.

---

**Previous confusion**

As one could easily show, (wrong expression)
$$\left.\frac{\delta }{\delta J(x_1) J(x_2)J(x_3)J(x_4)} Z[J]\right|_{J=0}=D(x_1-x_2)D(x_3-x_4)+\, {\rm perm}.$$

However, doesn't the product of the propagators $D(x_1-x_2)D(x_3-x_4)$ describe particle 1 going to particle 2 and particle 3 going to particle 4, and thus making two disconnected graphs? What is actually meant by "disconnected graphs" in QFT?

As Andrew had pointed out that the answer was the functional differentiation was done to the partition function, not the generating function of the connected Green's function, i.e.
$$\left.\frac{\delta }{\delta J(x_1) J(x_2)J(x_3)J(x_4)} W[J]\right|_{J=0}=D(x_1-x_2)D(x_3-x_4)+\, {\rm perm}.$$

---

But then it was intriguing to find that the partition function, built from the generating functional of the connected Green's functions, produced disconnected graphs.

Because, graphically, the disconnected graphs kind of provided a (mis?)conception that it was particle propagating $x_1\rightarrow x_2$ and $x_3\rightarrow x_4$, as if they were two non scattering process. However, the assumption for the calculation of scattering amplitude was to use $$S=1+iT$$ where the forward scattering was removed at the very beginning as an assumption. Thus, if felt that, the disconnected graphs not only should be removed, but they ought not to appear in the first place.

How does the functional differentiation of the partition function produce the disconnected graphs?

Comment: (a) I guess you are assuming $S$ is the action for a free field? (b) I think you've switched the normal definitions of $W$ and $Z$; normally $W$ is defined as $\ln Z$, where $Z$ is the partition function and $W$ is the generator of connected graphs, (c) indeed you should find the four point function is zero for a free field if you differentiate the generator of connected graphs. There are some more details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram#Connected_diagrams:_linked-cluster_theorem

Comment: @Andrew But what about the $D(x_1-x_2)D(x_3-x_4)$? didn't they represent disconnected graphs?

Comment: Yes they do. That term shouldn't be there.

Comment: My guess is that you differentiated the partition function (what is normally called $Z$) and not the generator of connected graphs $W$. That would yield the disconnected terms you found.